# sanitize the_title() in wordpress posts loop

Tags: php, wordpress

i am using a while loop in wordpress and i want to create my own link to a post:

```
<?php $query = new WP_Query( array('post_type' => 'knowledgebase', 'posts_per_page' => 20, 'knowledgebase-categories' => $var_id ) ); ?>
<?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
<a href="/knowledgebase/article/"><?php sanitize_title(the_title()); ?></a>
</article> <!-- .et_pb_post -->
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

i am trying to sanitize the title of each post using:

```
sanitize_title(the_title());
```

but its just not changing it at all.

if i do a: `var_dump(sanitize_title(the_title()));`

it jsut returns `string(0) ""`

how can i sanitize the title (`the_title()`) in my wordpress/php code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the_title() function *display* the title, to *return* it you have to use the_title('','',false) or get_the_title() .

see doc: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_title